# networkx: diameter gives 13 want to find what are those nodes or distance

Tags: networkx, graph-theory

I want to find the farthest nodes. I used diameter and it gave me an integer value, what should i do to get those points at the start and end of the diamete?
i.e find the farthest points in a graph by using some function.

Answer (score 1):

The nodes on the *periphery* are those nodes separated by a distance of *diameter*. Easy to calculate these in networkx. For some connected graph *g*:

```
n1, n2 = nx.periphery(g)
diameter_nodes = nx.shortest_path(g, source = n1, target = n2)
```

note that this assumes you will have exactly two nodes on the periphery. In general, this is not the case and you will have to implement some logic to determine which shortest path you want to calculate. Also, not all pairs of nodes in the periphery necessarily have a distance equal to the diameter. so this is something else to be cautious of.

Answer (score 0):

The `nx.diameter` seems like it's only to find the distance of the longest shortest path between nodes and none of the built in functions in the `networkx.algorithms.distance_measures` [(docs)](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable//reference/algorithms/distance_measures.html) module seem to compute what you're really looking for. To get the furthest nodes, one option is to use a sequence of calls to `nx.single_source_shortest_path_length(G,n)` where `G` is the graph and `n` is the source node. This returns the length of the shortest paths from `n` to all nodes in `G` as a dict keyed by the nodes and the values are the distance from the node to the source node `n`. Then you can look through these dicts to find which pair(s) of nodes have the longest length. Something like this should work.

```
def get_furthest_nodes(G):
    sp_length = {} # dict containing shortest path distances for each pair of nodes
    diameter = None # will contain the graphs diameter (length of longest shortest path)
    furthest_node_list = [] # will contain list of tuple of nodes with shortest path equal to diameter
    
    for node in G.nodes:
        # Get the shortest path from node to all other nodes
        sp_length[node] = nx.single_source_shortest_path_length(G,node)
        longest_path = max(sp_length[node].values()) # get length of furthest node from node
        
        # Update diameter when necessary (on first iteration and when we find a longer one)
        if diameter == None:
            diameter = longest_path # set the first diameter
            
        # update the list of tuples of furthest nodes if we have a best diameter
        if longest_path >= diameter:
            diameter = longest_path
            
            # a list of tuples containing
            # the current node and the nodes furthest from it
            node_longest_paths = [(node,other_node)
                                      for other_node in sp_length[node].keys()
                                      if sp_length[node][other_node] == longest_path]
            if longest_path > diameter:
                # This is better than the previous diameter
                # so replace the list of tuples of diameter nodes with this nodes
                # tuple of furthest nodes
                furthest_node_list = node_longest_paths
            else: # this is equal to the current diameter
                # add this nodes tuple of furthest nodes to the current list    
                furthest_node_list = furthest_node_list + node_longest_paths
                
    # return the diameter,
        # all pairs of nodes with shortest path length equal to the diameter
        # the dict of all-node shortest paths
    return({'diameter':diameter,
            'furthest_node_list':furthest_node_list,
            'node_shortest_path_dicts':sp_length})
```

Note, this solution assumes that the graph is connected (strongly connected for directed graphs), which yours should be since you got a solution for the diameter using `nx.diameter`. This should have similar runtime as the call to the diamater because that function does similar steps, it just doesn't keep all the path links and nodes that result in the diameter. Note the `furthest_node_list` item in the return dict will have each pair of nodes twice just in the opposite direction (if nodes `a` and `b` have shortest path equal to the diameter, both `(a,b)` and `(b,a)` will be in the list).